# Issue with recursive calling timeout using a anonymous function call to pass dynamic values to keyframes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a issue thats now cracking me up. from making a stack exceed javascript call to passing dynamic values to my keyframes. What I had to do was i had to play animation from top to bottom of page but it should be dynamic like first top grid animation then 2nd n so on, meaning y-axis would change after a successful animation on x-axis say at 50px then after a certain duration y should be 100px say n again same x [10 to 100 iterations] for a particular y each time. So i have tried below. I think the only issue i am facing is of timeout to change m after each recursive call.

```
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
var bbox = svg.getBBox();
var viewBox = [ bbox.x, bbox.y, bbox.width, bbox.height ].join(" ");
svg.setAttribute("viewBox", viewBox);
var count = 0;

var s1 = document.querySelector('svg');
var s2=window.getComputedStyle(s1);

setTimeout((function a() {

    if(count==1000) {
      return false;
    }
    count=count+100;

    m=parseInt(count)+"px";
    // console.log (s2.getPropertyValue('--m')); 
    document.querySelector('svg').style.setProperty('--m',m);

    a();

})(), 19000);
```

css

```
 svg
{

    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    top:8px;
z-index:2000;

width: 10%;

transform:translate(var(--m),0%);
position:absolute;
animation:animate2 4s linear ;

padding:0px;

}

@keyframes animate2
{
    0%
    {
    transform:translate(var(--m),0%);
    }

    20%
    {
    transform:translate(var(--m),50px);

    }
    30%
    {
    transform:translate(var(--m),0);

    }
    40%
    {
    transform:translate(var(--m),50px);

    }
    50%
    {
    transform:translate(var(--m),0);

    }
    60%
    {
    transform:translate(var(--m),50px);

    }
    70%
    {
    transform:translate(var(--m),0);

    }
    80%
    {
    transform:translate(var(--m),50px);

    }
    90%
    {
    transform:translate(var(--m),0);

    }

    100%
    {
    transform:translate(var(--m),50px);

    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timeout code isn't right.

```
setTimeout((function a() {

    if(count==1000) {
      return false;
    }
    count=count+100;

    m=parseInt(count)+"px";
    // console.log (s2.getPropertyValue('--m')); 
    document.querySelector('svg').style.setProperty('--m',m);

    a();

})(), 19000);
```

If you break down your first argument to `setTimeout`, the expression has the structure.

```
(
  function a() { ... }
)
()
```

The `()` is going to *call* the expression before it, the function `a`. The expression then becomes the *return value* of `a`, which is going to be `false` or `undefined`. This value is then passed as the first argument to `setTimeout`, which isn't correct; `setTimeout` needs a *function*.

If your intent is to have a timeout loop, try this instead:

```
function updateProperty() {
  if(count==1000) {
    return false;
  }
  count=count+100;
  m=parseInt(count)+"px";
  // console.log (s2.getPropertyValue('--m')); 
  document.querySelector('svg').style.setProperty('--m',m);

  setTimeout(updateProperty, 19000);
}

// Run the first time
updateProperty();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but idk why it gave me stack exceed when i had tried the same code i dont remember what i had missed using same code which you had tried but now the timeout works. I have checked now animation is not working as i had expected the m had to change after one animation cycle

Comment: Maybe you were accidentally calling `setTimeout(updateProperty(), 19000);` or similar before.

Comment: yeah maybe but thanks again you understood the problem rightaway and almost solved 90% of it. I have checked now animation is not working as i had expected the m had to change after one animation cycle can you check this too in my code. it plays one cycle but i wont it to change multiple times